# Unity android build Giving Build Method Exception

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When i build the game unity says eror in console and then crashes, this all began when i tried to ad ads to the game, previuosly it built with no problem i have reinstalled different unity versions multiple times but the same error seems to occur:
THis is the same error i get Just before a Dilogue box [This one-->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUWWM.png) Saying 1 exception was raised by workers:See the Console for details

`

```
`UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <434908727417408abd02bbd1a0835ef8>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <434908727417408abd02bbd1a0835ef8>:0 
0x00007ff748d7826d (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x00007ff748d7ee29 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007ff749d02cc3 (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00007ff74a3a3ebd (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00007ff747e3f392 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x0000024b0d4efae3 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x0000024b0d4ef9fb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x0000024b0d4ef740 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
0x0000024b35209005 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
0x0000024b3214e4cb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
0x0000024b35093e23 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
0x0000024b35083d43 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
0x0000024b350739a3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
0x0000024b0c43f36a (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x0000024b0c43f183 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x0000024b0c430afb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI ()
0x0000024b0b95d697 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x0000024b0c42e1bb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x0000024b0d82a59b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
0x0000024b0d82a403 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
0x0000024b0d829f4b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x0000024b0d829e03 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x0000024ac551b21b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x0000024ac5502ae8 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x0000024b0d827273 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x0000024ac5500cfe (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
0x0000024ac55007fb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x0000024ac550725b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
0x0000024ac55056e3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
0x0000024ac550561b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
0x0000024ac5500a83 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x0000024ac5500133 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x00000248791bffcb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x0000024ac42a0fa3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel)
0x0000024ac42a0993 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x0000024ac42a074f (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
0x0000024ac42a066b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)
0x0000024ac42a04bd (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x0000024ac42a0576 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_intptr_intptr& (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007fffdc77feb4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3445] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fffdc6be764 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fffdc6be8fc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3113] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff748c9cc34 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff748c7c4d4 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff748c770e5 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<void>
0x00007ff748dc12ca (Unity) Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
0x00007ff7497e2b28 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x00007ff749d334b1 (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0x00007ff7497e293a (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
0x00007ff749d342cd (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x00007ff749d2e019 (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
0x00007ff84110e7e8 (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007ff84110e229 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x00007ff749d08ce3 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff749d0d72b (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff74b0c224e (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ff8405c7614 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ff8424226a1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart`
```

`

I tried to build an android game with ads and it kept crashing

Comment: You need to look in the editor.log file to see what's actually failing. Search for `stderr`.

Comment: where is the editor.log file

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html